# Recover Ubuntu 18.04 after accidentaly removing python3

Tags: networking, configuration

Ok so I am an old geezer and thought Ubuntu (18.04.2 LTS) didn't need python, at least not python3. Big mistake, after I removed python3, nothing works anymore. I could recover it by reinstalling everything again, especially, in `/var/log/apt/history.log` I can find everything that was removed.

However, my network does not work anymore (why would need python3 for having a working network...).

So my question is, how do I recover my network without python3 and without the ability to install anything?

I have tried to reconfigure `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static IP address, but this does not seem to get picked up. Rebooting and my interface is still not configured.

Any idea?

Comment: Removing Python 3 will break a lot of utility scripts in the system, including but not limited to Netplan components.  This may explain why your system is no longer behaving.  Python is a HUGE portion of system interaction so when you remove Python you remove a huge portion of system utilities.  Short story is: **don't remove Python**

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to

```
ifup <interface>
```

Also needed to configure a nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` (which disappeared when I removed python3 for some reason...)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```